# Java Code Visual Representation of Slope in 3D Space

Tags: java, user-interface, 3d

My last question involved getting the syntax right, this question is:

How should I best go about showing a 3D representation of a line between 2 points?  I've calculated the slope, now I simply want to make a window appear and display a cube like this: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=slope+between+%282%2C6%2C1%29+and+%283%2C5%2C0%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=slope%20between%20%282,6,1%29%20and%20%283,5,0%29)

```
        public static double calcSlope(Point p1, Point p2){
        //math to calculate the slope
        double slope1 = (p2.getY()- p1.getY())/(p2.getX()-p1.getX());
        double angle1 = Math.atan(slope1);
        double distance1 = (p2.getY()-p1.getY())/Math.sin(angle1);
        System.out.println("distance: " + distance1);

        double slopeFinal = 1/distance1;

        return slopeFinal;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        double x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2;

        x1 = 5;
        x2 = 7.5;
        y1 = 3.25;
        y2 = 4;
        z1 = 0;
        z2 = 1;

        Point point1 = new Point(x1, y1, z1);
        //declaring new variables of class Point
        Point point2 = new Point(x2, y2, z2);
        //in Point y2 is = y, but y1 is also = y Point (x,y,z) serves as a placeholder where "x" is just
        //a placeholder

        double slope = calcSlope(point1, point2);
        double angle = Math.atan(slope);

        System.out.println("Your Slope is " + slope);
        System.out.println("Angle of entry is " + angle);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a BIG question, you're going to have to use some 3rd party library for 3D graphics as java doesn't natively support it*. I would suggest you look at jmonkey engine but thats just my personal preference: http://jmonkeyengine.com/.

*technically java3D does exist but it still doesn't come with java as standard and it is a largely abandoned project